# Nexmo - Undefined method send_message in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vonage

I am trying to send an sms using nexmo gem,

The code was working fine up till a couple of days ago.
[image]

```
def send_sms
    @number = params[:number]
    @nannytel = params[:phone]
    nexmo = Nexmo::Client.new(
    key: 'xxxxxxx',
    secret: 'xxxxxxx'
    )

    notification = "The contact number is following #{@nannytel}"

    response = nexmo.send_message(
      from: "SENDERID",
      to: @number,
      text: notification
    )

    if response['messages'].first['status'] == '0'
    flash[:success] = "Yayy!  We just sent you details for the nanny "
    redirect_to root_path
    else
    flash[:alert] = "Uh Oh! Something went wrong, please try entering your number again"
    redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

Above is the method in pages controller

Comment: which version of `nexmo` gem you are using?

Comment: It's the latest one 5.0.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please modify following code

```
response = nexmo.send_message(
  from: "SENDERID",
  to: @number,
  text: notification
)
```

AS

```
response = nexmo.sms.send(
  from: "SENDERID",
  to: @number,
  text: notification
)
```

above changes are needed as per [documentation](https://github.com/Nexmo/nexmo-ruby/tree/v5.0.2#send-a-text-message) for version `5.0.2`

OR

Use version `4.8` instead of `5.0.2`

```
gem 'nexmo', '4.8'
```

Comment: Downgrading the gem did the job :)
Thanks a lot Ganesh